# Flutter/Dart - Open a view after a delay or break before

Tags: flutter, dart, delay, flutter-futurebuilder

In the question ["Open a view after a delay"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49072957/flutter-dart-open-a-view-after-a-delay), [copsOnRoad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6618622/copsonroad) gives the
following result:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

// 1. Option with Timer
Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
  // 5s over, navigate to a new page
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Screen2()));
});


// 2. Option -- Using Future.delayed class
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
  // 5s over, navigate to a new page
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Screen2()));
});
```

I would like to give the user an option to stop the execution of Navigator.pushNamed
during the 5 seconds while waiting. How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can define a bool that if it is cancelled or not then push or not like:

```
import 'dart:async';

bool isCancelled = false;

// 1. Option with Timer
Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
  // 5s over, navigate to a new page
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Screen2()));
});


// 2. Option -- Using Future.delayed class
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
  if(!isCancelled )
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Screen2()));
});

and a button to change state of isCancelled
```

Comment: If I push the button again, would the ```Future.delayed``` or ```Timer``` be continued to be executed?

Comment: you can do anything you want in button onTap