# How to automatically navigate to a new page and send parameters after a fixed duration

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a quiz page which has a button 'end quiz', which navigates to the new page when the user taps on it. It also sends info like questions attempted and options selected to the new page.

I want to have a timer which automatically ends the quiz and does all that the button did.

I have got an idea on how to navigate to a new page after a delay using this:
import 'dart:async';

```
Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
  // 5 seconds over, navigate to Page2.
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Screen2()));
});
```

[link to where I got this info from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49072957/flutter-dart-open-a-view-after-a-delay)

Now where I exactly do I place this so as to also get all the data from the widgets the user interacts with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your `init` Function Exit Use This :

```
@override
  void initState() {
       Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
          // 5 seconds over, navigate to Page2.
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Screen2(arguments: { send your data here ..... })));
        });
        )
```

Dont Forget to Use `Stateful` Widget

Answer (score 0):

```
 timer() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 5000));
    //enter you code to save the data here here
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => child));
  }
```